# fwrite to STDERR resulting in error in executable script

Tags: php, fwrite, stderr, command-line-interface

I have a strange issue. Only in an executable php script this error happens, and I have no idea why

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

I have following examples:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    87 Sep 10 16:55 test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    33 Sep 10 17:10 test.php
```

Where the file ./test is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
fwrite(STDERR, "test\n");
```

and the file test.php is (exact same, just missing the shebang):

```
<?php
fwrite(STDERR, "test\n");
```

I made some tests on that machine and it's behavior is really strange:

```
# ./test 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

# php -q test.php 
test

# php -r 'fwrite(STDERR, "test\n");'
test
```

Has anyone an idea why fwrite to STDERR does not work (only) in executable php files?

`PHP 5.4.28 (cli) (built: May 19 2014 15:39:12)`

Comment: Having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is gone when I use the shebang `#!/usr/local/bin/php`. Makes sense, since php was compiled from source.

But I still don't understand why this happens on the other path. I tried to look into phpinfo using the 'wrong' shebang and I still get `PHP Version 5.4.28` as version, so there aren't multiple installations.